# Is it possible in WordPress to add editable sections in the dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I made a website for someone, and I would love to import this website into WordPress. I've never worked with WordPress before, but I'm starting to like it alot! I just have one question: Is there a plugin to let my customer add sections (like a text-, video- or bannersection) in the website, via the dashboard, without me (the developer) helping him/her all the time?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry btw if my English is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend the flexible content field functionality of http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/

There's a bit of a financial outlay, but it's well documented and the developer is extremely repsonsive.

Here's a quick intro on how you might use it.

https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/dev-tutorials/creating-flexible-content-with-advanced-custom-fields/

I recommend using it with the plugin Timber to really supercharge your WordPress development: http://upstatement.com/timber/

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).  It allows you to seamlessly implement more CMS-like features into Wordpress.  You can define areas throughout the backend where the customer can add different kinds of content (text, videos, images, etc)